# Mongo Database sorting and Indexing

Tags: mongodb, sorting, optimization, indexing

In following mongoldb execution plan, Fetch stage is returning only 3006 records, so why "sort stage" is considering 721381 records which can be seen in the value of "works" field of sort stage?
As sort stage is considering 721381 records, I am getting "Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit." error.

`

```
db.mycollection.find({ $and: [ { state: "Active" }, { expires_date: { $gte: new Date(1451586600000), $lte: new Date(1666003832377) } }, { $or: [ { last_checked: { $lte: new Date(1658267660509) } }, { last_checked: { $exists: false } } ] }, <some more filters>}]}).sort({last_checked:1}).explain("executionStats");

{
        
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : false,
                "errorMessage" : "Exec error resulting in state FAILURE :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.",
                "errorCode" : 96,
                "nReturned" : 0,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 5186,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 721379,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 721379,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                        "nReturned" : 0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1324,
                        "works" : 721381,
                        ....
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "SORT",
                                "nReturned" : 0,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1318,
                                "works" : 721381,
                                "sortPattern" : {
                                        "last_checked" : 1
                                },
                                "memUsage" : 33564004,
                                "memLimit" : 33554432,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                        "nReturned" : 3006,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1305,
                                        "works" : 721380,
                                        "advanced" : 3006,
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                "nReturned" : 3006,
                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1304,
                                                "works" : 721379,
                                                "advanced" : 3006,
                                                "docsExamined" : 721379,
                                                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "nReturned" : 721379,
                                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 102,
                                                        "works" : 721379,
                                                        "advanced" : 721379,
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "expires_date" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "expires_date",
                                                        "keysExamined" : 721379,
                                                        "seeks" : 1,
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

`

A possible solution is to fetch the data and sort in our application.

Comment: Use option `{allowDiskUse: true}` (which is default since MongoDB version 6.0)

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit but still It doesn't answer why "SORT" stage doesn't process data from immediate previous "FETCH" stage.

Comment: I assume `nReturned` is just the number of **estimated** documents. When data is read, then it may exceed the limit. Explain plan scan the index on `keyPattern: { expires_date: 1 }` which does not make much sense and does not match the query condition. What are your indexes and what is the full query?

Comment: Complete query:   db.myCollection.find({ $and: [ { state: "Active" }, { expires_date: { $gte: new Date(1655697260509), $lte: new Date(1658289260509) } }
, { $or: [ { last_checked: { $lte: new Date(1658267660509) } }, { last_checked: { $exists: false } } ] }, { $or: [ { processingState: "Processed" }
, { processingState: { $exists: false } } ] } ] }).sort({last_checked:1});       and indexes are present for expires_date and processingState.